# How to catch Unhandled Exception ?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - How to implement one catch'em all exception handler with resume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337702/c-sharp-how-to-implement-one-catchem-all-exception-handler-with-resume)

I want to add method that will catch Unhandled Exception. 
I know how to do it in the Appdomain level - but i want to do it on the application level ( add Unhandled Exception method that will be called in case Unhandled Exception will appear )

How to do it?

Comment: In your eyes, what is the difference between the AppDomain level and the Application level?

Comment: Do you have an assembly with multiple appdomains? If not catching exceptions at appdomain level is what you want, isn't it?

Comment: "i want to do it on the application level" - then specify the application type.