# JIT debugger always shows up when my app crash instead of my crash report

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, exception, crash-reports

I have tried using [Exception Reporter](http://exceptionreporter.codeplex.com/) as well as other methods such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/338030/342740 but no matter what I use,  the windows crash error / JIT always show up instead of my own crash report.

A simple example would be using the nCalc to evaluate a failed expression out of a try and catch block.

```
string formula = "10,1 * 231,2";
Expression exp = new Expression(formula);
exp.Evaluate();
```

Basically I have no idea of why it fails and what I can do to work it around.

The test VM I am using is a Windows XP SP3 with .Net4 installed, there is no visual studio or anything else is a clean WINXPSP3 install.

Sample image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the down vote that explains a lot, if I am lacking of something on my post, it would be more useful if u could point that out prior to down voting it. Also I did look around but did not find relevant information to this issue using the terms I was using to search.

Comment: I've upvoted you. You've put a fair amount of information in the question - ignore the plum who downvoted you with no explanation.

Comment: @JamieKeeling appreciated the up vote, I don't really mind the down vote but when there is no comments sometimes its hard to know what people want from you and while I would like to provide it, I can't guess it myself when I believed I had enough posted to describe the scenario.

Comment: So, likely the problem is outside of .NET, otherwise the two other methods would have given you some information.  What do the stacks look like when it crashes in the debugger?

Comment: @PeterRitchie like I mentioned above I've made a very simple error with nCalc, to evaluate an invalid expression, for example "10,1 * 10,2" the evaluation doesn't like the comma and will fail. Using the Exception Reporter on the computer I have VS installed it will show up but after I compile and send it to the VM it will overlap with the windows default crash error windown, I will update my post with the evaluate function I was using that produces the error.

Comment: Can you post your code including try/catch blocks?

Comment: @Guapo Now you have me confused.  If there is no Visual Studio installed in the VM, you can't possibly cause the JIT debugger to show up because it's not installed.

Comment: @PeterRitchie thats what I don't understand as well all I have installed aside from the out of box windows is the .net4 framework I haven't installed anything else.

Comment: @Nick the code to catch the unhandled exception is in the 2 urls above described (2 different methods I have tried) the code that gives the unhandled exception error is posted above and ofc does not have a try and catch.

Comment: @PeterRitchie my bad I did say JIT always show up but its not the actual JIT debug window we have when VS is installed, its the one from the framework that describes the JIT error etc, I have updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: @Guapo Okay, that's not the JIT debug window; that's the .NET Framework default exception message box.  If you're getting that but not catching exceptions, you're likely got a corrupt .NET framework install.

Comment: @PeterRitchie even if the application works when I remove the faulty code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, what you're seeing is not related to the JIT. It is the Windows Forms default [`ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) handler (it won't appear in a WPF application). By default, this dialog will only appear when you're not attached to a debugger.

In your `Main` method, add the following line:

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

This will force exceptions to pass by the `ThreadException` handler, allowing you to handle them and display your own exception dialog. More information [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157905.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will try that and report back.

Comment: @Julien, I'm pretty sure it should be `UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException` in order to handle the exception with user code. @Guapo, I'd also add a `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;` handler in case an exception is thrown on a non-UI thread.

Comment: @JulienLebosquain well I am not sure as to the non-UI but it seems to be catching pretty much everything now without any issues so far. I will try what you mention and see if it happens and if what you said also corrects it thanks.

Comment: Ops, meant to say @Nick on the above my bad.

Comment: @Guapo: Check out the MSDN documentation linked above. It does a good job explaining the differences between those two unhandled exception events.