# default exception handling

Tags: vb.net, exception

What im trying to do within my project is every time i raise a

```
try
      ...
catch ex as exception
      ...some logging code
end try
```

Have it so that there is a class predefined somewhere to execute some code when a catch is triggered. not sure if it's possible but it would make my life easier and alot less duplication in my code.

something like

```
public sub NullReferenceException()
       runLogginfunction()
end sub
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337702/c-sharp-how-to-implement-one-catchem-all-exception-handler-with-resume

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to catch and log exceptions in a very general way. This is a bad practice. You should program to avoid exceptions and only use exception handling for exceptional circumstances. Otherwise you are just making your code buggy and hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can't both catch an exception and have it automatically logged.  You can have one or the other.  For desktop apps, you can use the UnhandledExceptionEventHandler to catch and log exceptions, in ASP.NET you can use the global.aspx to the same thing.  Or you can catch the exception, and decide what to do with it -- which can include logging, but will have to be handled manually.

Answer (score 0):

why this would not work?

```
 try
       ...
 catch ex as exception
       NullReferenceException(ex)
 end try

 module allstuff
    public sub NullReferenceException(ex as exception)
           runLogginfunction(ex)
    end sub
end module
```

Comment: it would work but what im trying to do is not have to put any loggin functionality within each try catch every time i write one.