# Does a SQL Client need to be installed on a PC for a C# application to access a database?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

I have created a C3 WPF application that manages data on a database.
So far, I have successfully used it on 3 separate PC's, but it crashes on the forth. The exception is:

```
Faulting application name: LakeSmitFautLog.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x503b19ee
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e2111c0
Exception code: 0xe0434352

Application: LakeSmitFautLog.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Stack:
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at LakeSmitFautLog.MainWindow.LoadComboBoxes()
   at LakeSmitFautLog.MainWindow..ctor()
   at LakeSmitFautLog.initxaml.btnEnter_Click(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at LakeSmitFautLog.App.Main()
```

On the first 3 PC's, there is a stand-alone MS SQL Client installed, but not on the one providing the error.
In the app, I am referencing `System.Data.SqlClient`, yet it seems that this isn't enough.

As titled above, does this forth PC need a stand-alone SQL Client installed?

[Edit] Possible solution requires disabling the firewall from the SQL Server. The issue may be that it is kicking people out that hasn't got a local IP (The forth PC is from a different venue, with a different IP range).

Comment: You might want to try catching the exception and see what the actual error message is. Usually all database operation should be guarded for exceptions since they can fail for a multitude of reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **No**.

From the documentation:

> The .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server (SqlClient) uses its
>   own protocol to communicate with SQL Server. It is lightweight and
>   performs well because it is optimized to access a SQL Server **directly**
>   without adding an OLE DB or Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) layer.
>   The following illustration contrasts the .NET Framework Data Provider
>   for SQL Server with the .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB. The
>   .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB communicates to an OLE DB data
>   source through both the OLE DB Service component, which provides
>   connection pooling and transaction services, and the OLE DB provider
>   for the data source.

[image: Microsoft Sql Client Database Access]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx

So... what's up?

As other commentators have pointed out, you are light on exception handling; the actual exception does not appear to be caught anywhere.

Given that you have said the same exe is working on 3 other machines, you really need the actual exception message to decide whether it's:

1. Environmental (perhaps the machine can't connect to the database server)
2. User based (the user it's running as does not have permission to connect to the database server)
3. Time based (the server just wasn't available then so the connection failed.)

If you wanted to post the code of LoadComboBoxes (or at least the bit that does the database work) then that might help us to provide some further suggestions.

Comment: Great response! Appreciate the effort you put in to clearly explain this scenario to me... I am updating the code, and will post a reply based on the outcome

Answer (score 1):

no, this is not due to SQL Express, is not mandatory you have it installed to run an app, but it does seems that you have a DLL missing. I would start by checking if you have framework 4.0 intalled. Also, if you are using libraries that are not in the .NET framework make sure you set Copy Local = true on the required reference properties.

Comment: What makes you think he has a DLL missing?

Comment: everything working on 3 boxes and on the forth isn't...seems like an enviroment issue, not an application issue...

Comment: Exactly; configuration more likely than deployment. CopyLocal will not come into play unless using other  drivers like Oracle etc; and even then they are usually installed to the GAC.

Comment: @Diego: There's still nothing to indicate a missing DLL. It is obvious from the stack trace that there is simply an error opening an SQL connection.

Comment: @Bigtoe: Look at the stack trace. We're talking SQL Server (SqlClient), not 3rd party like Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 100% certain that you do not need a SQL client installed to access the database.

Comment: To prevent me from redoing an entire new question, would you possibly know what exactly this application error is from?

Comment: It's an internal exception in you system I'm afraid. It appears to be an exception which was not caught; the message above states "The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception". I would suggest you put a global exception handler in your app domain to catch these. But the main issue appears to be in the MainWindow Constructor loading the comboboxes. Are you sure it's not as simple as an invalid connection string somewhere? What is your LoadCombo boxes doing?

Comment: See my comment above. You need the exception message to know what the problem is, which is not included the error report you posted. Catch the exception and log the message. What I can tell you according to the stack trace is that you failed opening the connection to the database. Perhaps the connection string has the wrong `Data Source=`, or that computer cannot reach the database due to a network error (unresolvable hostname, etc). Try pinging the host.

Comment: I appreciate all the help! I shall add catch() statements to my numerous SQL methods (Although I should have done that already :/ )
@Bigtoe, it is a simple transaction querying the database to populate 3 comboboxes with 1:Venue, 2:Priority, 3:Type, so users can easily select what they want to see.
Thanks for the helpful information, I will be sure to check!

Comment: Don't forget about adding a Global exception handler to the routine, even for non database issues these can be a life saver, have a look at stackoverflow qutesion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337702/c-sharp-how-to-implement-one-catchem-all-exception-handler-with-resume

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how your LoadComboBoxes routine is opening the connection. Is there something in the connection string that's not right on that machine? The .nEt framework should already include all pre-reqs for connecting to Sql.