# Throw single custom exception from Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

How can I write a *catch all exception handler* in a Class Library project in C#, which will give the outside caller only one Custom Exception on any exception occurring in the library.

Most nearest solution I found is to implement a `Facade` class, call low level classes from it, and write `try..catch` in every call from Facade which will throw single custom exception if any exception occurs underneath.

I searched for solutions, but got it only for Web Applications (using Application context for catching exceptions)
e.g. [How to implement one "catch'em all" exception handler with resume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337702/c-sharp-how-to-implement-one-catchem-all-exception-handler-with-resume)

I need to implement it at Class Library level or at consumer of library level, but good if that can be done by write minimum exception handling statements.

Comment: You mean there is an existing library that can throw whatever and you want to make it so that it appears as if it throws only exceptions of a (new) specific type?

Comment: @Jon I am writing a library and I want it to throw only one single custom exception outside.

Comment: Have you considered using an `AOP` framework?

Comment: @ImranRizvi: Well, then don't write anything else than `throw new MyCustomException(...)` from your code. What's the problem with that? Although I have to say that this doesn't sound like a universally good idea. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: take a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15913/Better-Exception-Handling-with-AOP

Comment: @Jon I was just wondering if they have something for this, no coder likes to write same try..catch in different methods , my library can contain 500+ methods.. and buyer of it wants only one custom exception containing actual exception as inner exception.

Comment: You can do it with AOP... But you shouldn't. It's just plain annoying, and really a LOT of work to do correctly.

Comment: @ImranRizvi: I don't understand why you need to try/catch at all. If the buyer wants you to only throw `CustomException`, all you have to do is write `throw new CustomException`. You can make this configurable at runtime by simply writing a `throwException` method somewhere and routing everything though it, but that doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: @jon where to write throw new CustomException ? can you give any example? can it be written at only single place?

Comment: @Jon I suppose this is for when his code *causes* an exception that needs catching and wrapping. However, I agree with you, it's a terrible plan. As a consumer of the API I would want more granular control over exceptions using the `catch` mechanisms built-in, not catching a general `CustomException` and then having to do sub-filtering only to re-throw it again because it's not the one I want. Imran: for easily wrapping methods with try-catch, AOP via PostSharp would suffice nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* use:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var exception = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        if (exception != null && exception.Source == "MyLib")
        {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    };
```

But seriously, don't do it. Exceptions shouldn't be handled this way, you should catch them locally.

Comment: +1 for the warning. Although, this makes sense only if you want to log the exception (when possible) and shut down upon that.

Comment: Thanks, it maps to the requirement, is it the only option available? I will also consider your warning.

Comment: Where should I write this and how? I want to write prefrebly in class liberary...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) but make sure you read the documentation thoroughly - there are some exceptions that you can't handle, and it also depends on version of the framework that you are using.

Comment: Wouldn't that apply to errors in the whole application, not just the class library?

Comment: Yes it would - I missed the part that the scope is just the library. However, you could inspect the stack trace and check where does the exception originate from.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Won't it only catch issues in the current `AppDomain`? This would need subscribing for each `AppDomain` in use.

Comment: if it is done in librarys bootstrap code then it will be done for each AppDomain in which the library is loaded. As OP seems to care only for exceptions in his library, this should suffice.