# Can we write extension method for all methods?

Tags: c#, exception, extension-methods

I want to do extension method to all method for try-catch. In following You can see code block - but it doesn't work

```
public static class TryCatchExtention
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public static void WithTryCatch(this MethodBase method) 
    {
        try
        {
            //method.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error : {0} " + ex.Message);
            throw new ApplicationException("");
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a delegate and pass that one as parameter to your function `WithTryCatch`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133199/net-global-exception-handler-in-console-application or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337702/c-sharp-how-to-implement-one-catchem-all-exception-handler-with-resume

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a satisfactory description of what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Declare it like that:**

```
public static class TryCatchExtention
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public static void WithTryCatch(this object theClass, Action theMethod) 
    {
        try
        {
            theMethod.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error : {0} " + ex.Message);
            throw new ApplicationException("");
        }  
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var yourClass = new YourClass();
//Pass here the method to be wrapped with a `try-catch` block
yourClass.WithTryCatch(this.YourMethod);}
```

Or with params:

```
yourClass.WithTryCatch(()=> this.YourMethod(params...));}
```

**Notice:**

This extension method extends any `class` object and only supports the `Action` delegate which:

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and does not return a
>   value.

You can always support more overloads for more delegates signatures.

Comment: #yemrekeskin Welcome!

Comment: @YairNevet Just curious: Why did you call `theMethod.Invoke()`and not just `theMethod()'

Comment: @okrumnow I think it is the same. no specific reason.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

In your example your extension method will  be available when you're working with `MethodBase`instances, in other words, when using reflection (the metadata representation of  methods and constructors).

On the other hand, if you want that extension method to be always available you should extend the `object` class.

Nevertheless do not get confused about the **difference between extension methods and aspect oriented programming**. If what you want is to make a kind of an interceptor to all method calls then i'd suggest you to see what aspect frameworks are available. 
I'm not used to that kind of programming so i can't really advise you